# How to get a new row on a dataframe by summing some of the rows using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to sum the values of only 2 rows on my dataframe, keeping the other. Alternatively, i would like to get an extra row with the sum of those 2 rows.

My initial dataframe would be:

```
columna_a <- c('a','b','c')
columna_b <- c(300,400,250)
columna_c <- c(1,2,3)

df1 <- data.frame(columna_a, columna_b,columna_c)
```

And this is the desired output:

```
nuevo_columna_a <- c('a','b+c')
nuevo_columna_b <- c(300,650)
nuevo_columna_c <- c(1,5)

df2 <- data.frame(nuevo_columna_a, nuevo_columna_b,nuevo_columna_c)
```

I feel like this should be easy to do, but I can't figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## base R

```r
df1bc <- subset(df1, columna_a %in% c("b", "c")) |>
  transform(columna_a = toString(columna_a)) |>
  aggregate(. ~ columna_a, FUN = sum)
df1bc
#   columna_a columna_b columna_c
# 1      b, c       650         5
```

to which you can easily `rbind` the original with

```r
subset(df1, !columna_a %in% c("b", "c")) |>
  rbind(df1bc)
#   columna_a columna_b columna_c
# 1         a       300         1
# 2      b, c       650         5
```

## dplyr

If you're inclined to learn the "tidyverse" by using the `dplyr` package,

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(columna_a %in% c("b", "c")) %>%
  summarize(
    columna_a = toString(columna_a),
    across(-columna_a, ~ sum(.))
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(filter(df1, !columna_a %in% c("b", "c")), .)
#   columna_a columna_b columna_c
# 1         a       300         1
# 2      b, c       650         5
```

---

Note: I used `toString` which is really just a shortcut for `paste(..., collapse=", ")`. Feel free to instead use `paste(..., collapse="+")` if you prefer the different collapse string.

Answer (score 2):

For folks who are used to spreadsheets, it can seem natural to add a summary row to the bottom of a data frame, but it is an unusual operation in R. Typically, we want data frames to contain one observation per row and one variable per column. Summary rows usually violate this principle.

The specific summary row that you are creating varies according to the `class` of the column, so you might want to define a little function to do it for you:

```r
summary_func <- function(x) {
  c(x[1], if(is.character(x)) paste(x[2], x[3], sep = " + ") else x[2] + x[3])
}
```

Once you have your summary function, you can apply it in `dplyr` like this:

```r
reframe(df1, across(everything(), summary_func, .names = "nuevo_{.col}"))
#>   nuevo_columna_a nuevo_columna_b nuevo_columna_c
#> 1               a             300               1
#> 2           b + c             650               5
```